# Trying to create a websocket link between a phone app and a website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am creating an app for my capstone project in college.  This app will be used as a check-in app that lets the user keep track of appointments and actually check-in for their appointment using their phone.

I am using node and mongodb to create appointments, and for the user to find businesses using the app.  The only problem I am having at the moment is establishing the link between the app and the website the businesses will use to monitor check-ins.  I figured that I would probably be using socket.io for this.  I have yet to implement socket.io into the app because I am still trying to wrap my head around how to implement this connection.

What I would like to do is have an event handler on the check-in button on the app, and when the user tries to check-in have it send a "notification" to the website.  Does anyone have an tips on how I would implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.IO is exactly how you do this.  You really should do the [demo application on the Socket.IO homepage](http://socket.io/), as it is exactly what you are looking for.

Basically, when the check-in button is pressed, just do something like:

```
socket.emit('checkin', { /* put data, like an ID, in this object */ });
```

On the server:

```
socket.on('checkin', function (data) {
    // Your data passed will be in the data var
});
```

Socket.IO serializes all of the data and what not for you.  Just emit.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Brad.  This websocket stuff seems to be a little more difficult for me than node and mongo.  I sort of understand that demo application, but making it work how I want it to is hard to grasp.

Comment: @DanielLeach, If you can use Node and Mongo, and are having trouble with Socket.IO, then you are thinking too hard.  :-D  An event emitted on one side is fired on the other.  It's that simple.  Socket.IO wraps all the communication for you.  You just need to fire events.

Comment: I have the example working, but I am having trouble understanding how I would send from the app to the website.  They will both be located on the same server, but in different paths as two totally separate entities.  How would I reference the paths so that they can talk to one another?  I know I have to be making this out to be harder than it really is.

Comment: What do you mean by paths? Once connected, you emit events on both sides, and they are raised on the other side.

Comment: So do I just need to add node/socket-io/etc to both the app directory and the website directory?  Then forever both node processes and listen for the event on the website?  The theory behind this is what is confusing me.  I am using an Ubuntu EC2 instance to host both the app and the website.  What I mean by paths is two different extensions to the url like for example: 55.555.555.555/app and 55.555.555.555/website.

Comment: Install socket.io into your Node application's directory with npm. You do not need to add any files to your website. The Socket.IO client is served by your Node application automatically.